# How to let a DigitalMicrograph script object be notified when an image is closed

Tags: dm-script

We can attach DM script objects to image events and imageDisplay events via the ImageAddEventListener() and ImageDisplayAddEventListener(). Are there event map message to support the "image close" event? I tried both the "image_about_to_close" and the "imagedisplay_about_to_close" and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DigitalMicrograph differentiates between **Images** (The data object), **ImageDisplays** (an object rending the data), **ImageDocuments** (The object which is represented by the saved file), and **DocumentWindows** (the window object in which an *ImageDisplay* is shown).

The event you are asking for belongs to **DocumentWindows** and not to Images nor to ImageDisplays. Accordingly, you need to register it with a DocumentWindow object. This is done with the command `WindowAddWindowListener`.

BTW, there are two similar events you can capture, one is `window_closed` and the other is `window_about_to_close`. The later is fired *before* the user is prompted to save unsaved data, the other one *after* such a prompt but - inconsistently - *before* the window is actuallay removed from memory. (There is still a pointer to it at that time.)

The following script attaches the two events. I've put it into a background-thread for easier testing.

```
// $BACKGROUND$
Class MyWindowListenerClass
{
    MyWindowListenerClass( object self )    Result("\n object 0x"+self.ScriptObjectGetID().Hex()+" created.")
    ~MyWindowListenerClass( object self )   Result("\n object 0x"+self.ScriptObjectGetID().Hex()+" destroyed.")

    Void HandleAboutToClosedAction( object self, number e_fl, DocumentWindow Win )
    {
        Result(GetTime(1)+": Window about-to-closed message : 0x" + Hex(e_fl,8) + "\n" )
    }

    Void HandleClosedAction(object self, number e_fl, DocumentWindow Win)
    {
        Result(GetTime(1)+": Window closed message : 0x" + Hex(e_fl,8) + "\n" )
    }
}


Void main()
{
    Object          objListener
    Image           img
    DocumentWindow  win
    String          messagemap
    Number          ListenerID

    img:=RealImage("Test",4,100,100)
    img.ShowImage()
    win = img.imageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetWindow()
    messagemap      += "window_closed:HandleClosedAction;"
    messagemap      += "window_about_to_close:HandleAboutToClosedAction;"

    objListener = Alloc(MyWindowListenerClass)
    ListenerID  = win.WindowAddWindowListener( objListener, messagemap)

    While(!ShiftDown()) 1==2
    win.WindowRemoveWindowListener(ListenerID)
}

main()
```

A final note: Having an DocumentWindow closed does not necessarily mean you have released the *image* as well. As long as some script or other code keeps a reference to the *Image* it will stay in memory! Be sure to not do this, or you might see memory leaks in your scripts. It is generally saver to 'store' ImageIDs as member variables than image-objects in such a case, as they don't "lock" the Image.

Comment: Thanks. In the past, we can add key listener to ImageDisplay via ImageDisplayAddKeyListener() so I assume that ImageDisplay in an object to be "displayed". A follow up question, how do we catch the "slice changed" (i.e. displayed layers changed) event for a 3D image? The message map "slice_changed:<Handle>" of ImageAddEventListener() used to work in GMS 1.8 but no longer in GMS 2.3 now.

Comment: Yes, there was a change. The event is now with the imagedisplay  and the event message is 'slice_property_changed'. The [book here](dmscript.tavernmaker.de/) has an example of it in the tutorial *How to display layer-specific ROIs in a 3D image*. If you need more help. please post as separate question.